# remove extra symbols and adjust lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have text file (test.txt) that looks exactly like this (same number of options for every instance):

```
# a comment

first: info about first:  option1 \
                          option2 \
                          option3

second: info about second: option1 \
  option2 \
  option3

#third: info about third: option1 \
#                         option2 \
#                         option3

fourth: info about fourth: option1 \
                           option2 \
                           option3 \
```

I want to reorganize the text so it looks like this:

```
a comment first: info about first: option1 option2 option3 
second: info about second: option1 option2 option3 
third: info about third: option1 option2 option3 
fourth: info about fourth: option1 option2 option3
```

Comment: Hello, @Nadal do you have the same number of options ever every line?

Comment: Why is "first" supposed to join with "a comment"? There is no trailing backslash on the comment line.

Answer (score 2):

With a single sed program:

```
sed -E '
    # remove leading comment chars
    s/^[[:blank:]]*#+[[:blank:]]*//

    # label "a" for branching
    :a
    # if trailing slash:
    /\\$/ {
        # read next line
        N
        # remove backslash, newline, leading whitespace and comment char 
        s/\\\n[[:blank:]]*#*[[:blank:]]*/ /
        # branch to label "a"
        ba
    }

    # remove blank lines
    /^[[:blank:]]*$/d
' test.txt
```

Perl is pretty compact though: read paragraphs (`-00`) and replace leading whitespace and comment chars for each line in the paragraph (the `/m` and `/g`  modifiers), and remove trailing backslash-newline.

```
perl -00 -lanE 's/^\s*#*\s*//mg; s/\\(?:\Z|\n)/ /g; say' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^#/ /g;s/\\/ /g' file | xargs | sed 's/option3 /option3 \n/g'

a comment first: info about first: option1 option2 option3 
second: info about second: option1 option2 option3 
third: info about third: option1 option2 option3 
fourth: info about fourth: option1 option2 option3
```

`sed 's/^#/ /g` replaces `#` with empty spaces and `^` matches for the `#` position within the strings. Then `sed s/\\/ /g'` replaces backslashes `\` with empty spaces.

`xargs` lines up and creates equal white spaces between the words.

finally, `sed` adds new lines after every word  "option3"

Comment: use `s/\\$/ /g`  and `'s/\n//g'` is redundant and you have used xargs to do so. and can you provide better way to solve with out hard-coding option3.